# How to make a http request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing a quick exercise about HttpRequest in JavaScript. I want to get data from the localhost. So made a request in client end like below.

```
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:4000/', true);
  httpRequest.send;

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(httpRequest.readyState ==4 && httpRequest.status ==200){
      var json = httpRequest.responseText;
      console.log(json)
    }
  }
```

And the server side

```
app.get('http://localhost:4000/',(req,res) => {
  res.status(200).send({username: "123"})
})
```

However, it doesn't work, I can't get the username data in client. How should I MODIFY the code?

Comment: `httpRequest.send()` is a method, you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the introductory documentation for Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).

The route is defined using **only** the path, not the full URL.

```
app.get('http://localhost:4000/',(req,res) => {
  res.status(200).send({username: "123"})
})
```

Note that if you aren't loading the HTML document from your Express server you will have to [use CORS to grant permission to read the JSON across origins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068).

Comment: Thanks, I changed the route to ' / ', but still got nothing